# How to make conditional auto-size of ag-grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have grid that may has different set of columns depending on user settings. So if it has a lot of columns - everything is ok, bot if fox example 3 columns, grid has redundant  empty space if header and in grid body. I want to auto-size grid to container width in such case. I tries to use `api.sizeColumnsToFit()`, but it working bad for aa lot of columns. So how can I check if grid currently has this redundant space?
[grid with redundant space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A9eJE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Column Flex](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/column-sizing/#column-flex)

As long as you apply the column property `flex` on a column, it will fill the entire available space in the grid.